# Drawing a Marquee on ReCharts

Tags: marquee, bounding-box, bubble-chart, recharts

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to use a a bubble chart in which multiple bubble items can be selected at the same time. A user can perform selection by drawing a marquee (a bounding box) just like the oracle OJ charts feature. But since oracle charts are on the Jet framework, I couldn't seamlessly use it as a component in my React Project.

[OJ Charts Marquee Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBRWT.png)

Source link: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=bubbleChart&demo=selection

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScatterChart, Scatter, LabelList, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend } from 'recharts';

const data = [
              {x: 100, y: 200, z: 200},
              {x: 120, y: 100, z: 260},
              {x: 170, y: 300, z: 400},
              {x: 140, y: 250, z: 280},
              {x: 150, y: 400, z: 500},
              {x: 110, y: 280, z: 200}
];

class RechartBubble extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <ScatterChart width={400} height={400} margin={{top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20}}>
        <CartesianGrid />
          <XAxis dataKey={'x'} type="number" name='stature' unit='cm'/>
          <YAxis dataKey={'y'} type="number" name='weight' unit='kg'/>
          <Tooltip cursor={{strokeDasharray: '3 3'}}/>
          <Legend/>
          <Scatter name='A school' data={data} fill='#8884d8'/>
             <LabelList dataKey="x" position="center"/>
      </ScatterChart>

      </div>
    );
  }
```

I would really appreciate any pointers in this direction.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks.